# Can i connect multiple phone via WiFi in android

Tags: android, wifi, connect

I need to connect multiple phones to each other using wifi, without there being any internet though.

So i was thinking if this can be done by turning on the hotspot on one phone and allow the others to connect to it, can this be done ?

Or is there any other way to connect multiple phones via wifi ?

Any help is appreciated .. thnQ

Comment: Not exactly sure of the full details here. If you are using a home Wifi router then simply having all phones connected to the same router will mean they share the same connection. However, if you are trying to use an app that needs internet connection it will probably not support local play and your tethering idea would be best for a device that does have internet.

Comment: what i need to do is make one phone some sort of server, so that he can broadcast messages to all other phones connected to it, but they don't have to be connected to the internet !!

Comment: If that is the case then you won't be able to make use of any external services and will have to write an app your self. Easiest I can think of is to use a network broadcast. Looks like this kind person has knocked up a good example already: https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP

Comment: i'm sorry, but what kind of external services are you talking about ??

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to broadcast a message to all phones using your app that are connected to the same network. Most android apps use something like google's notification service for this. However, as you have no internet access you can use an internal method such as network broadcast messages. These are message that can be sent to any listening application on the same network broadcast range. Which your devices will all have from the DHCP response from the router.

Comment: yes but there will NOT be a router, so can i somehow use one phone's hotspot and configure it to be a broadcaster, and all the other phones connected to it's hotspot can receive the messages ??

Comment: Network broadcasts should work fine using a single phone as a hotspot. The steps to enable tethering can be found here: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en

Comment: but can i tweak it programatically in order to make my own broadcasting app ??

Comment: Yep, you can filter the message / port so that you only get messages your application wants to see.

Comment: No problem at all I will add the details to here as answer in case other come looking for a similar solution. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send and receive UDP messages you can using the following technique:
https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP

The simplest way to explain this is that the UDP packages can be transmitted on a network with no particular destination set. Applications can pick this up and then decide if they want to handle the message or not.

To connect the devices you can use either a mifi dongle or put one of the phones into tethering mode:

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en

Of course this is limited in range to the hosting mifi or phone.